# Input field accepting only numbers without firing events when input other caracters

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

I'm not satisfied with the default behavior of the html number input, I would like to have a simple input that accepts only numbers.

I created this directive :

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: 'input[numbersOnly]'
})
export class NumberDirective {

  constructor(private _el: ElementRef) { }

  @HostListener('input', ['$event']) onInputChange(event) {
    const initalValue = this._el.nativeElement.value;
    this._el.nativeElement.value = initalValue.replace(/[^0-9]*/g, '');
    if ( initalValue !== this._el.nativeElement.value) {
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
  }

}
```

The issue I'm facing is that the "event.stopPropagation()" does not stop the event propagation, an event is fired even if the input value does not change from the user point of view.

How can I stop the event propagation when the field value has not changed ?

Edit :
For better understanding, here is a stackblitz example :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-numbers-only-directive

Comment: This might be the issue.

"You can use Event.cancelable to check if the event is cancelable. Calling preventDefault() for a non-cancelable event has no effect."
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: I've checked your example, event you captured from the directive is not cancelable. Hence, it propagates as usual.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, do you have any suggestions to achieve the initial targeted goal in a clean way ? An edit of the stackblitz code would be much appreciated.

Comment: try use HostListener 'keyDown', not HostListener 'input'

Comment: @Eliseo the event is still fired with the `keydown`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really think there is a way to stop this event using directive with `HostListener`.

<del>Angular detected this event before you listener was called so stopping propagation will not affect Angular events like `ngModelChange` to which you react in parent component.</del> (no proof for that so I may be wrong)

I would suggest to provide own event indicating value change and emit it when you really want it to be emitted:

```
export class NumberDirective {
  @Output() numberChanged = new EventEmitter<number>();

  constructor(private _el: ElementRef) { }

  @HostListener('input', ['$event']) onInputChange(event) {
    const initalValue = this._el.nativeElement.value;
    this._el.nativeElement.value = initalValue.replace(/[^0-9]*/g, '');
    if ( initalValue === this._el.nativeElement.value) {
      this.numberChanged.emit(initalValue);
    }
  }

}
```

Then you can replace `ngModelChanged` binding with `numberChanged`:

```
<input type="text" [ngModel]="value" (numberChanged)="onChange($event)" numbersOnly/>
```

Demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-numbers-only-directive-a2mv6e

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, as I'm using some fields on forms, and listening to the form value changes, this will make a different case for the numerics fields. I will give it a try as soon as I'll get my hand on my computer.

Comment: I got my solutions for both cases, the bounty would be awarded as soon as possible. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For usage in reactive forms, I ended up making a custom component implementing `ControlValueAccessor` :

The component declaration (extract) :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'number',
  template: `
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="value" numbersOnly/>
  `,
  ...
  ]
})
export class NumberInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  ...

  set value(value) {
    const tmp = value.replace(/[^0-9]*/g, '');
    if(tmp && tmp !== '' && +tmp !== +this._value) {
      this._value = +tmp;
      this.onChange(this._value);
    }
  }

  ...
}
```

Usage :

```
<number [formControl]="formControl"></number>
```

[Here is the stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-numbers-only-directive-2)