# How to create angular directive text box only allow numbers space and fraction

Tags: javascript, angular

How to create a directive for fraction number so a user can enter the only fraction number just like below.

```
"10 1/2" // Valid format
"10.25" // Valid format 
"10    1/2" // Invalid format extra spaces found 
"dummy 12 1/2" // Invalid string format found
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Input field accepting only numbers without firing events when input other caracters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47555587/input-field-accepting-only-numbers-without-firing-events-when-input-other-caract)

Answer (score 1):

The following should work..

first create the directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[exampleDirective]'
})
export class TestDirective {

 constructor() {}

 @HostListener('input', ['$event'])
 ngOnChanges(evt: any) {
  const pattern: RegExp = new RegExp(/^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$/);
  if (!pattern.test(evt.target.value)) {
   evt.srcElement.value = evt.srcElement.value.substring(0,evt.srcElement.value.length - 1); // this will erase the last char that does not match the pattern...
  }
 }
}
```

and then select it in your input

```
<input exampleDirective/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

1) In your html file

```
<input type="text" (change)="onChange($event.target.value)"/>
```

2) In your typescript file

```
onChange(value) {
const reg = /[1-9][0-9]*(?:\/[1-9][0-9])*/; // -> Regex for matching only numbers and fractions
if (!reg.test(value)) { // test() matches string with regex
  // reset textbox here.
}
  }
```